# Replica set members not resyncing after primary goes down

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set with 3 nodes, I have a server titled dev-6 which is running mongo 3.0.6, and dev 5 which has 2 mongos on it running 3.2. I'd like for dev 6 to be the that is the primary, and so I've added the other 2 nodes to its initiated replica set, once I do that it becomes primary and the other 2 nodes begin to sync to it. Here is a screenshot of how my setup looks like when I bring down dev 6, and then is brought back up.

[image]

As, intended dev 6 is secondary, and so is dev 5: 27018. What I'm wondering about though is why is dev 5 saying there's no one to sync with, but dev 5:27019 is saying that its syncing with dev 5 :27018.

Im now going to follow the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/) instructions to make dev 6 the primary, here is the result now.

[image]

Dev 6 is the primary, but what Im trying to understand is how come the other dev 5 instances are not connecting with dev 6. Before some conclusions are jumped to, I am able to ping dev 5 from dev 6 and visa versa, the `/etc/hosts` profiles contain the ip addresses for one another.

**EDIT:** Im basing the replica set being unable to connect with the following message `"lastHeartbeatMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",`. This seems to be fixed if I run `rs.config(//current cfg)` or if I add or remove a replica set.

Answer (score 1):

Your replica set seems to be healthy in both cases. All secondaries have applied the last operation from the primary's operation log (optime/optimeDate are the same), moreover lastHeartbeat is slightly behind the dev 6 time. In regard to the lastHeartbeatMessage refer [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20144) jira issue, that says:

> When secondary choose a source to sync, it will choose a node who's
>   oplog is newer (not equal) than self, so after startup，when all nodes
>   have some data，the oplog will be same，so secondary cannot choose a
>   sync souce, write after a write operation happens, primary will have
>   newer oplog，secondary can successfully choose a targe to sync from，the
>   error message will disappear.

Comment: Tried this out and it didn't work. What I did was create a new collection and insert an item which didn't start a sync.

Comment: How do you know the replica members are out of sync? Have you tried, for instance, to write while one of them was down and when it was up again to check if there was the latest write (on a secondary you can use `db.collection.find().readPref("secondary")`)?

Comment: Im basing this on seeing this line on the shards `"lastHeartbeatMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",`. I added more details of when the RS's sync and when they aren't.

Comment: As jira says, it can be a bug. I would try to check actual changes.

Answer (score 0):

The error "could not find member to sync from" I usually associate with replica set members not being able to talk to one another. Either because of firewall or credential issues.

I know that you can ping the servers but have you tried connecting to the primary mongo instance from one of the secondaries using the mongoclient?

`mongo vpc-dev-app-06:27017`

with appropriate user credentials if necessary.

Has anything possibly changed in the mongod.conf as part of the upgrade?

Comment: Im able to connect to both mongos from either server. Its interesting since they start out syncing and then can't resync.